2010s-era Analog story referring to something like the "bouba/kiki" effect
This XKCD alludes to the Bouba/Kiki effect which describes how the sounds of some words affect the likely meaning assigned to them. In the 2010s (I think) in Analog (almost certainly) there was a story called something like "The Skeet-Wozzle Test" that involved linguistics research very similar to the above.  ISFDB confirms that I don't have the title quite right, unfortunately, and "Test" is way too generic to search on.

An ISFDB title search for English-language short fiction published in 20__ with the title "the % test" gets only 34 hits.

Huh. I just assumed that it would be a lot more than that

"The Skeekit-Woogle Test" (2006) by Carl Frederick, Analog, March 2006.
The story begins:

"Imagine," said Kendrik, "a language that has the word skeekit
and also the word woogle."
Standing in front of his boss's desk, data-tablet in hand, he paused. He hoped the man would invite him to sit, but Victor merely stared with his usual mixture of boredom and condescension.
"Why should I imagine it?" Victor said. "Does this have anything even remotely to do with epidemiology?"
"I believe we're on the verge of a pandemic." Nervously, Kendrik cast his gaze around the trophy office before bringing them to rest on his data-tablet. "On the basis of epidemiological evidence"—Kendrik raised his head to meet the section chief's eyes—"I believe
we're in the midst of an epidemic of synesthesia."
"Of what?"
"Synesthesia. The most common form is 'colored hearing.' Music perceived as having colors, or a particular word having a particular shape. That sort of stuff. A cross-wiring of the senses."

Just to confirm that the test is almost exactly the same:

"Okay." Kendrik sat. "Skeekit and woogle. One word means a hard-boiled egg, and the other means a shard of broken glass." He slid forward on the chair.  "The test is to tell me which word means what."
"It's obvious," said Victor without pause. "A woogle is the egg and a—what is it?—a skeekit is the shard of glass."


So close and yet so far

@DavidW now I'm dying to know: what was "skeekit" and "woogle" associated with in the story? (I'm familiar with the bouba/kiki effect, by the way).

@AndresF. It's pretty much exactly the same “Okay.” Kendrik sat. “Skeekit and
woogle. One word means a hard-boiled egg, and the other means a shard of broken glass.” He slid forward on the chair. “The test is to tell me which word means what.”
